# Python script won't run from .bat file, Task Scheduler, or cmd prompt

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a Python script which works great when running from Eclipse, IDLE, double clicking on the .py file in the directory folder.  I need to automate this to run every night but I cannot get it to run from the Windows Task Scheduler so I've written a .bat file and it does not work either.

Python script:

```
import urllib.request
import time
from lxml import etree
import datetime
import csv
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

today = datetime.date.today()
ts = int(time.time()) - 86400
tsend = int(time.time())
#ts = 1461253877
#tsend = 1461340277

dailyReport = "URL_GOES_HERE".format(ts, tsend)

with urllib.request.urlopen(dailyReport) as url:
    soup = url.read()
saveFile = open('{}_dailyIdleReport.xml'.format(today),'wb')
saveFile.write(soup)
saveFile.close()

tree = etree.parse('{}_dailyIdleReport.xml'.format(today))
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag, root.attrib)

zonarFile = open('{}_idleReport.csv'.format(today),'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(zonarFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['Asset ID', 'Event Type', 'Idle Length', 'Cost'])

for assetidle in root.findall('assetidle'):
    for element in assetidle:
        for event in assetidle.findall('event'):
            fleet = assetidle.get('fleet')
            eventtype = event.get('type')
            length = event.find('length').text
            tlength = length
            (h, m, s) = tlength.split(':')
            result = ((float(h)/1) + (float(m)/60) + (float(s)/3600))
            cost = (result * 1.5) * 1.80
            displayCost = '${:,.2f}'.format(cost)            
            zonarFile = open('{}_idleReport.csv'.format(today),'a', newline='')
            outputWriter = csv.writer(zonarFile)
            outputWriter.writerow([fleet,eventtype,length,displayCost])
            zonarFile.close()            
            #print('Asset #:  %s  %s  %s  %s' %(fleet,eventtype,length,displayCost))

fromaddr = "myemail@server.com"
toaddr = "myemail@server.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "The Zonar %s" %'{}_idleReport.csv'.format(today)
body = "The Zonar Daily Idle Report is attached."

filename = "{}_idleReport.csv".format(today)
attachment = open("C:\\Users\\PeggyBall\\workspace\\ZonarCSCProject\\src\\{}_idleReport.csv".format(today), "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
body = "The Zonar Idle Report for {} is attached.".format(today)
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.email.serverhere', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("email_username", "email_password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

Current .bat file:

```
@echo off
c:\Users\PeggyBall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe c:\Users\PeggyBall\workspace\ZonarCSCProject\src\DailyIdleReport.py
pause
```

CMD output from above .bat file (this output is expected but the .xml and .csv files are never created from .bat):

```
eventlist {'end': '1461716317', 'ver': '1', 'count': '38', 'start': '1461629917'}
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Previous .bat files that didn't work:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\PeggyBall\workspace\ZonarCSCProject\src\DailyIdleReport.py %*
pause

@echo off
C:\Users\PeggyBall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:\Users\PeggyBall\workspace\ZonarCSCProject\src\DailyIdleReport.py %*
pause
```

Here is the error message:

```
eventlist {'ver': '1', 'end': '1461624597', 'count': '33', 'start': '1461538197'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PeggyBall\workspace\ZonarCSCProject\src\DailyIdleReport.py", line 68, in <module>
    attachment = open("C:\\Users\\PeggyBall\\workspace\\ZonarCSCProject\\src\\idleReport.csv","rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\PeggyBall\\workspace\\ZonarCSCProject\\src\\idleReport.csv'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've removed the double \ to a single \ but that didn't work either.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The script does run. It just errs out at the `attachment()` line. Are you sure there is not another .py file in different folders? Notice error line does not format `today` with underscore in csv file.

Comment: I cleaned out that folder, there were other .py files with different names but I've removed everything.  Can I not use a variable in the file name for the attachment?  My plan was to have the date of the report in the file name.

Comment: Yes, you can. Try running script again pointing to correct .py. Did code ever save xml/csv files with dates in directory?

Comment: What should the line be in the bat file?  And yes, the XML and csv files do save in that folder when I run the file from Eclipse or the .py file but not when I run the .bat file.

Comment: Does same exact traceback occur? I see no reason why your .bat file produces a different result than using the Python IDEs. I simply cannot reproduce your situation. All I can say is carefully check your file paths.

Comment: The script does run from the .bat file but the files (.xml or .csv) are not created unless running the script directly from Eclipse or IDLE.  I took the email portion out of my script as it looked like the program failed when looking for the attachment however before it reaches that point two files should be created:  2016-04-26_dailyIdleReport.xml and 2016-04-26_idleReport.csv and this does not happen when running the .bat or from Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider designating an absolute path in all files. Currently, in `open()` of your external files, relative paths are assumed which will be problematic if batch files and command lines are run externally.

Try saving .xml and .csv files to current path of .py script and any call to .py (IDEs or command line) will use such an absolute path. Below uses the `os.path.join()` to concatenate directory and file names. This function is platform agnostic (Windows, Mac, Linux) and avoids the back or forward slash needs and works in deployment to other users as no hard-coded paths are set.

```
import os
...

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF RUNNING SCRIPT
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# EXTERNAL FILE NAMES
xmlfile = os.path.join(cd, '{}_dailyIdleReport.xml'.format(today))
csvfile = os.path.join(cd, '{}_idleReport.csv'.format(today))

with urllib.request.urlopen(dailyReport) as url:
    soup = url.read()
saveFile = open(xmlfile, 'wb')
saveFile.write(soup)
saveFile.close()

tree = etree.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.tag, root.attrib)

zonarFile = open(csvfile,'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(zonarFile)
outputWriter.writerow(['Asset ID', 'Event Type', 'Idle Length', 'Cost'])

for assetidle in root.findall('assetidle'):
    for element in assetidle:
        for event in assetidle.findall('event'):
            ...
            zonarFile = open(csvfile, 'a', newline='')

...
# ATTACHMENT
attachment = open(csvfile, "rb")
```

Comment: Parfait, you are a lifesaver!  This solution worked and I can't thank you enough for all of your help with this!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!